# How to select data from database and keep inside Languages file using Codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create languages editor for user using it in Codeigniter3.
But I don't much understand about this process so I try to fetch data from my DB in My_controller and using foreach in a file in Languages folder.

**My Issue** I can't view my data inside of Languages in Language folder.
So does Codeigniter have another ways to fetch data from DB and keep it inside of Languages.

and my function to select data from Database is working as well.

So if I have to use file  does Codeigniter3 will let me read,write,update,delete file from Language folder or not

Please help me some idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Language Class Extended DB](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Language-Class-Extended-DB) or refer the solution [How to create Codeigniter language files from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939931/how-to-create-codeigniter-language-files-from-database)

Comment: and this script will create it content or not? becuse when I have already create a file I have to write content inside that file too.