# create folder with nested php file in language folder after new language name is inserted into database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

in codeigniter, in applications/languages folder, a new folder with language name with nested php file have to be created each time when new language name is inserted into database.

```
if(!is_dir('$fold')){
                mkdir('$fold');
               }
```

this fold must be created in the existed language folder. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your question? whats the problem? any errors? any code you have already tried? You need to be as clear as possible when asking a question. You can modify your original question by clicking the _"edit"_ link.

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939931/how-to-create-codeigniter-language-files-from-database/23973204#23973204

Comment: There's barely a question here. **What is your specific problem?**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a new folder in application/{$language_name} given from your db, you need to have a flag in your table that have the languages

table_languages
 id | language | short | createdDate | exist
 xx    englis     en      28/03/2016     0

model.php

```
public function check_language(){
    $this->db->where('exist', 0);
    retrun $this->db->get('table_language')->result();
}
```

controller.php

```
public function create_folder(){
    $this->load->model('model_language');

    $new_langauge = $this->model_language->check_language();

    foreach($new_language as $item){
        if( ! mkdir(APPPATH . $item->language . '.php', DIR_READ_MODE, TRUE)){
            log_message('error', 'Don't have level to create folder');
            show_error('ERROR', 'Error creating folder' )
        }
    }
}
```