# CodeIgniter: usign db inside My_Lang

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, class, loader

I found this useful Internationalization code:

http://pastebin.com/SyKmPYTX

everything works well except I am unable to connect to database.

what I need:
1) I need to check last segment
2) this is my db

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `translate`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `trans_data`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `languages`;
/*Table structure for table `languages` */

CREATE TABLE `languages` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`key` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`default` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`display` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `languages` */

insert into `languages`(`name`,`key`,`default`,`display`) values
('GEO','ka',1,1),
('ENG','en',0,1),
('RUS','ru',0,1);

/*Table structure for table `trans_data` */

CREATE TABLE `trans_data` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Table structure for table `translate` */

CREATE TABLE `translate` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`lang` int(11) NOT NULL,
`data` int(11) NOT NULL,
`trans` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `lang_2` (`lang`,`data`),
KEY `lang` (`lang`),
KEY `data` (`data`),
CONSTRAINT `translate_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`lang`) REFERENCES `languages` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `translate_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`data`) REFERENCES `trans_data` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=340 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

in the first I need to do something like this

```
$this->db->where('key', end($this->segments));
$query = $this->db->get('languages');
$lang = $query->row();
if(empty($lang)){
     $this->db->where('default', 1);
     $query2 = $this->db->get('languages');
     $lang = $query2->row();
}
$lang_array = [
     "lang_key" => $lang->key,
     "lang_id" => $lang->id
];
$this->session->set_userdata($lang_array);

if(end($this->uri->segment_array()) == $lang->key){
     unset($this->uri->segments[intval($this->uri->total_segments() - 1)]);
}
```

after this functionality
then I need to download translates from database and save it in object with this query

```
SELECT TD.`name` , T.`trans`
FROM `translate` AS T
INNER JOIN `languages` AS L ON (T.`lang` = L.`id`)
INNER JOIN `trans_data` AS TD ON (T.`data` = TD.`id`)
WHERE (L.`key` = :lang_key);
```

and when I call from view

```
echo $this->lang->line('trans_key');
```

I need to get the value

but I do not undestand how to edit this class to do this job...

can you help me and edit this class for me?

thank you for future...

Comment: check this, maybe it's easier to implement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939931/how-to-create-codeigniter-language-files-from-database/23973204#23973204

Comment: it is easier but it is not wjat I need...

Comment: $this->CI =& get_instance(); not executing... if you help me to implement this code in class I can do other functions...