# Codeigniter doing translations from the database

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, translation

I have been looking around to see if I can learn how to do translations that come from a database.

My aim is to have an admin do the translations for each label in an admin console and when a user selects a language, the site will reload and it will load the translated options from the db instead of having multiple view files in different languages.

So far what I have is adding an extra segment in my url to accommodate different languages ex. www.testwebsite.com/Application/en-US/content

I plan on reading that segment, storing it into a cookie or session and when a new page loads, it retrieves that option from the cookie or session and always loads the right language.

As for the db structure, so far I have

id | label | language | translation

The main issue now is how do I load this properly? My experience so far has taught me that when I want to load a bunch of items from the database, it will come in an array form and in order to access it, I must add a for loop/ foreach loop.

Is there a way to replace the labels without them being in a loop? Or is there a better way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: There is no magic. You're going to have to write the code. If it were me and I was attempting to do what you are doing, I'd probably extend the lang class so it uses the database instead of lang files.

Comment: At the moment the plan is to use the database to get the translations. I prefer that instead of updating individual language files. The problem is accessing those translations from the loop and attaching them to the right labels. Perhaps I may need to extend the current controller class and just set all labels and then make every other controller that I use extend the new one.

Comment: check my answer here, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23973204/2275490