# Is there any possible way to set language key values programatically in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I would like to know is there any way to set language key values programatically in codeigniter?

Ex : if I'm using multiple languages such as English & French.

User should be able to select a language and edit the language key values programatically. I went through the codeigniter doc and i couldn't find a proper answer.

Codeigniter allows to change config file values but how to change language key values.

I'm using codeigniter 3.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939931/how-to-create-codeigniter-language-files-from-database/23973204#23973204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save language preferences in database or session, then you can grab that and set to your config:

```
$this->config->set_item('language', grab_from_db_or_session);
```

please see [this](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html#setting-a-config-item) for more details.

Comment: No this wasn't my question . I need to change language key values.