# How can I make CodeIgniter work with multi language using json files

Tags: codeigniter

I have a script that although has the option of multilanguage, it is designed in a way that only one language can be setup for all users, I have some json files that have the translated messages and I can only pick one language.

The chosen language is then written on the DB and accessed by a helper file:

```
if ( ! function_exists('get_phrase'))
{
    function get_phrase($phrase = '') {
        $CI =&  get_instance();
        $CI->load->database();
        $language_code = $CI->db->get_where('settings' , array('key' => 'language'))->row()->value;
        $key = strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $phrase));
        $langArray = openJSONFile($language_code);
        if (array_key_exists($key, $langArray)) {
        } else {
            $langArray[$key] = ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $key));
            $jsonData = json_encode($langArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            file_put_contents(APPPATH.'language/'.$language_code.'.json', stripslashes($jsonData));
        }

        return $langArray[$key];
    }
```

What I need help with is a way for the user to choose the desired language, and this selection to be stored in the session, so that different users can have different languages.

I'm not a CodeIgniter savvy, so a step by step on the changes and locations of files to be changed would be appreciated.

I have done some research on basic CodeIgniter multi language support, but they all fall on a different approach that is used on this script, by using hooks and directories for the languages.

Comment: I'm using something like: `$this->lang->line('wsl')?:'World Surfing Reserve';`. which means, if the item is translated in the pretended language, it displays otherwise it falls back to the string "World Surfing Reserve"; that's useful, because you don't loose control of your views text. In the language file (e.g.( application/language/PT), you can create all the required array items feeding it with a database call...

Comment: check also my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939931/how-to-create-codeigniter-language-files-from-database/23973204#23973204